# Prove that $g$ is a submanifold: $g (t,u,v) = (t^2,u^2,v^2,\sqrt{2}uv, \sqrt{2}tv,\sqrt{2}tu)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

We consider $g : (t,u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto (t^2,u^2,v^2,\sqrt{2}uv, \sqrt{2}tv,\sqrt{2}tu)\in\mathbb{R}^6$. I have to prove that $g(\mathbb{S}^2)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$.

$dg_{(t,u,v)}=\begin{pmatrix}2t&0&0\\ 
0&2u&0\\ 
0&0&2v\\ 
0&\sqrt{2}v&\sqrt{2}u\\
\sqrt{2}v&0&\sqrt{2}t\\
\sqrt{2}u&\sqrt{2}t&0\\
\end{pmatrix} $

So it proves that $g$ is an immersion (the rank is $3$ clearly) for $(\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\})$.

Now how to prove that $\mathbb{S}^2$ is homeomorphic to $g(\mathbb{S}^2)$ ? I must prove that $g$ is injective  ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can start by showing that $g$ is an immersion on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$, in other words $dg_{(t,u,v)}$ has full column rank.  The next step will be to show that $\mathbb{S}^2$ is homeomorphic to it's image $g(\mathbb{S}^2)$.

Comment: @Mnifldz so for the second step I have to show that $g$ is injective ?

Comment: @Maman - Do you know the difference between an immersion and an embedding? You already have that $g$ is an immersion. If you show that $g$ is injective, you will only have a continuous bijection between $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ and its image. To show that the two are homeomorphic, you'd also need the inverse to be continuous ... and you're done! :-)

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to use the fact that proper injective immersions are embeddings, and try to show that $g$ is proper.

Comment: @udit.m So I have to prove that $g^{-1}(\{1\})$ is compact ?

Comment: @udit.m Is it obvious that $g^{-1}(\{1\})$ is bounded ?

Comment: The map you have given is not even injective - antipodal points map to the same point in $\mathbb {R}^6$. Are you sure the domain is $\mathbb {S}^2$?

Answer (score 2):

In  fact, the map $g$ is $\bf not$ injective, as $g(u,v,w)=g(-u,-v,-w)$. It defines a map from the real projective space $\bf RP^2$ to $\bf R^6$.

$\bf RP^2$ is defined as the quotient of the sphere by the involution  $I(u,v,w)=-(u,v,w)$

It is easy to see that $g(u,v,w)=g(u',v',w')$ iff $(u,v,w)=(u',v',w')$ or $I(u,v,w)=(u',v',w')$, therefore the map $g$ descend to an injective map $\bar g$ from $\bf RP^2$, which is an homeomoprhims to its image.

Then one can say that there exixts a unique structure of a surface on $\bf RP^2$ such that the natural projection is differentiable and a local diffeomorphism, so in fact $\bar g$ is an immersion and an homemorphism onto its image therefore a diffeomorphism

Comment: So why $g(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a submanifold ?

Comment: $g(S^2)={\bar g} RP^2$ is the image of an injective immersion of a compact manifold.

Comment: Nice answer, but it is not clear to me why $\bar g$ is a homeomorphism onto its image - and this, in fact, seems to be the core of the question. Is it obvious, and I'm not seeing it, or does it need a bit of explanation?

Comment: RP2 Is compact, and a continuons injective map from a compact space Is an homeo onto its image