# Embedding maps from $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have been working on the following problem:

> **How can we get an smooth embedding from $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$**, using the fact that $f : {S}^2  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^6$ given by $f (x; y; z) = (x^2, y^2, z^2, \sqrt{2}yz, \sqrt{2}xz, \sqrt{2}xy)$ induces an smooth embedding from $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{6}$.

**Observation:** I already proved that $f : {S}^2  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^6$ induces an smooth embedding from $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{6}$. In fact, this can be found here, if anyone wants to read: [Prove that $g$ is a submanifold: $g (t,u,v) = (t^2,u^2,v^2,\sqrt{2}uv, \sqrt{2}tv,\sqrt{2}tu)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863719/prove-that-g-is-a-submanifold-g-t-u-v-t2-u2-v2-sqrt2uv-sqrt2t) .

I would appreciate if anyone could give me some help. Thanks

Comment: I would like to know why a downvote it is a valid doubt of someone. Should have make clear why such arrogant action.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to believe what you ask for is even possible?

Comment: I found it as exercise in different places, so I believe it is a known exercise of this area. Still I wasn't able to find the embedding using the fact that $f$ induces one in $\mathbb{R}^{6}$.